# Return from void function to another void function

Tags: c, syntax

```
void reserve(int x)
{
    stream = begin;
    if (begin == NULL)
    {
        begin = stream = (struct room*)malloc(sizeof(struct room));
        details();
        stream->following = NULL;
        printf("\n\t room booking is successful!");

    
        x = stream->room_period;
        printf("\n\t your room period is: period-%d", x);
        stream->room_period = x;
        
        return;
        
    }
```

After running details(), will the program automatically continue to run or some words need to be added ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function `detals()` terminate (returns) then the following line in `reserve()` will run which in this case is:

```
     stream->following = NULL;
```

`details` presumably sets the global variable stream.  Otherwise it's undefined behavior as `malloc()` does not initialize the memory being allocated.  I suggest you avoid global variables if possible and instead pass them those variables as arguments:

```
details(&stream);
```

In C we don't cast `void *` and I suggest you use the variable rather than the type as argument to `sizeof`:

```
        begin = stream = malloc(sizeof *begin);
```

You should check the return value from `malloc()`.  It will return
NULL on failure and this will cause the following `stream->following` to segfault.

Not sure why you read a variable then write it back again to the same place.  As `x` is an argument whatever you assign to it will be discard when the function returns.  At least in this sample `x` isn't serving any purpose and could just be eliminated.

```
        x = stream->room_period;
        printf("\n\t your room period is: period-%d", x);
        stream->room_period = x;
```

Maybe you just want to do this instead?

```
        printf("\n\t your room period is: period-%d", stream->room_period);
```

Your function is missing a `}` so this will not compile as is.

Comment: So adding return ; at the end of details() is ok already  ?  Will it automatically return to int main() instead ?

Comment: @GDydy It will return to caller, in the code you shared with us the line `stream->following = NULL` in `reserve()`[

Answer (score 1):

A `void` functions doesn't return a value to its caller, but it returns execution.

So the code following the call to`details()` will run once (and if) it returns.

If the function `details()` calls `exit()` or a similar function, then execution will not return and your process will terminate.

Aside:

1. Casting the result of `malloc()` is redundant and may hide a bug.
2. Assuming `malloc()` can not fail is very optimistic and risks undefined behaviour. Check its return value.